# X forwarding from a mac to Linux fails

Tags: linux, ssh, osx, xforwarding

I have been having problems recently while trying to ssh into linux servers (Ubuntu 14.04) from my mac (OSX Yosemite 10.10). This used to work fine until my latest update, where I systematically get a "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication".

The problem seems to be on the client side, as I can use X forwarding just fine from another mac with the same setting as far as I know. I tried to reinstall the latest XQuartz version but the problem remains unchanged. I also tried to change /etc/ssh_config to add "X11Forwarding yes", but without a visible change either

Any idea as where I should be looking to solve my problem?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `xauth` and similar stuff like in http://askubuntu.com/questions/377053/x11-ssh-issues-wrong-authentication ?